# How to get md-divider according to flex-layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox, angular-material

I know md-divider is for md-list but i want it in flex-layout

For Example:

```
<div layout="row" layout-wrap>
  <div flex="100"></div>
  <md-divider></md-divider>
  <div flex="100"><div>
</div>
```

Should get a horizantal divider between two divs and for the another case

```
<div layout="row" layout-wrap>
  <div flex="50"></div>
  <md-divider></md-divider>
  <div flex="50"><div>
</div>
```

Should get a vertical divider

How can i achieve this, any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<md-divider class="vertical-divider"></md-divider>
```

and in css

```
.vertical-divider {
    border-top: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid grey;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: it will not have any height right so need to specify the height in custom css only?